# Results reproducibility using Pytorch and Optuna for DNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, optuna

I have found the optimal results for 7 hyperparameter namely:

1. Number of layers,
2. Node size,
3. Activation functions,
4. learning rate,
5. momentum,
6. batch size,
7. optimizer

Using Optuna multiobjective optimization. I minimized the training and validation loss as my objectives. Since the number of tuning parameters are more I reduced the number of epoch per trail as 50. Then I got the best parameters, post Optuna optimization. I increased the epoch size and build the same model with `torch.manual_seed`. But the results obtained after the same 50th epoch is different from what I got in the Optuna results.

What is the reason am I missing anything? I want to reproduce the same results for the same condition!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to find the reason for improper reproducibility. In my code I used two different objective functions; def train(trial) and def layer(trial). I pivoted the second objective function into the train(trial). Also, specifying a manual seed is also important. Anyway there will be slight deviations of 0.0001%.

Comment: how you specify manual seed